# How to truncate table every day with php or cronjob?

Tags: php, truncate

I want to do truncate table automatically every day.I am using this method and it's working.

```
$truncate = "TRUNCATE TABLE myTable";
```

I am using up there code with a submit button click then truncate table it's so good working.

How I do this automatically truncate my table? I am trying now strtotime with if-else and ajax

Comment: What do you mean by *How I do this automatically truncate my table*?

Comment: You could do this a couple of ways. Create a cronjob that runs the php code to truncate the table or create a sql event that runs at specified times. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: Maybe you want something to automate that task for you? If you are on Linux: cronjob, on Windows: Scheduled Tasks

Comment: @jeff Yes.I am trying now strtotime with ajax: if ( strtotime == mytime) { truncate table code }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create this using MySQL only, read more about [MySQL Events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html)

> MySQL Events are tasks that run according to a schedule. Therefore, we
>   sometimes refer to them as scheduled events. When you create an event,
>   you are creating a named database object containing one or more SQL
>   statements to be executed at one or more regular intervals, beginning
>   and ending at a specific date and time. Conceptually, this is similar
>   to the idea of the Unix **`crontab`** (also known as a “cron job”) or the
>   Windows **`Task Scheduler`**.

for example :

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS my_truncater
  ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  DO
    TRUNCATE TABLE myTable
```

To repeat your event at a regular interval use `every` instead of `AT` :-

> To repeat actions at a regular interval, use an EVERY clause. The
>   EVERY keyword is followed by an interval as described in the previous
>   discussion of the AT keyword. (+ INTERVAL is not used with EVERY.) For
>   example, EVERY 6 WEEK means “every six weeks”.

so the example would be like :-

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS my_truncater
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOURS
  DO
    TRUNCATE TABLE myTable
```

for more details/features , checkout the [man page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) for the syntax of the `Events`, also it's important to check out the right [configurations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html) for the `Events` in MySQL.

---

The `cronjob` way :-

-- create an executable file [PHP file/SQL file ... etc]
-- assuming that you will go with the PHP choice, create a new file `example.php`

```
$query = "TRUNCATE TABLE myTable";

/* your mysqli/pdo connection & queries */
```

-- add the following command to a bash script to `/etc/cron.daily` directory :

```
$ php /path/to/example.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a cron job which calls a script which truncates the table in the database.